# Getting a complex text as a string

Tags: c#, winforms, string, text, console-application

```
abc @cnn("sujsl d(*) sfv @nor dsf ",dn,".",@tn); ator '`,`') sds
@cns1 or '`,"\','\",`') fdhg @cns2 sf \",dn,"; nj
```

How can I get this text as a string in C#. It can not be simply done due to containing `"` I would prefer to paste it, someway, as it is, rather than replcaing `"` with `\"` as my text already contains things like that

One way is, to paste it in a static text Box (textBox1) and then get it as Text of textbox (If I have to use this in a winform) e.g. `string st = textBox1.Text`

How this type of text can be got in a string variable without using a textBox?

Comment: replace all `"` with `""` and you have your string s = @"..."

Comment: @L.B This is a very large text actually an sql procedure. I want to build it through C#. So it is very much likely to make mistakes while replacing `"` with `""` but if I don't get any better way. Surely i will have to do that.

Comment: Bit hard to say without any context. Is it a constant? Have you tried using resources?

Comment: in re:  "It can not be simply done": I would tend to disagree with you; either via escaping individual characters or @-escaping. Why do you find that not simple? The rules for character escaping are straightforward to implement a function for very large texts, too.

Comment: In line with what Vman says, it's important to know how you are obtaining the text in the first place. Is it from a text file? Are you typing it in manually?

Comment: @Sami what mistakes are you likely to make?  Find/Replace (`Ctrl-H`) is pretty reliable in my experience.

Comment: Yes D Stanley and Reacher Gilt. I agree you. But @Vman 's question seems more attractive and answer is yes. But through a textbox and do not how to use resource without a hard-coded object. Could you please guide? Ichabod Clay yes I am typing it manually

Comment: So, if these are actually SQL commands, using a resource file as vman says would be ideal: see for details this url -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xhwfctz(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Yes @ReacherGilt thanks. Post it as answer. However i do not think specifying the SQL is necessary. But this way one does not need any replacement for using a text as string i think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good case for resource files. They will allow you to enter string literals without having to worry about escaping of any kind and are available to you programmatically.  See for reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xhwfctz(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. It saved my time and it would be bit efficient as well. i was just thinking about to write it in a file and them read from that, but thanks to you to introducing me to a very useful concept/technique

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck with your program.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), this may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry i know it. And your told link is guiding about much easier scenario. It is first line of my question statement as well. And too much discussed in comments